# Remove a route with IOperationFilter in SwashBuckle

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, custom-attributes, swashbuckle

I am looking for a way to show/hide WebAPI routes in the Swagger documentation using SwashBuckle in a configurable way. Adding `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` will indeed hide the routes but I'd need to recompile every time I want that to change.

I have looked into creating an `IOperationFilter` to work with a custom Attribute that I defined. That way I can decorate the routes with a `[SwaggerTag("MobileOnly")]` and check the web.config or something to see if the route should be shown. The Attribute is defined as such:

```
public class SwaggerTagAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string[] Tags { get; private set; }

    public SwaggerTagAttribute(params string[] tags)
    {
        this.Tags = tags;
    }
}
```

The `IOperationFilter` that detects the attribute is defined and the `IDocumentFilter` that removes the path is defined here:

```
public class RemoveTaggedOperationsFilter : IOperationFilter, IDocumentFilter
{
    private List<string> TagsToHide;

    public RemoveTaggedOperationsFilter()
    {
        TagsToHide = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TagsToHide"].Split(',').ToList();
    }

    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        var tags = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor
            .GetCustomAttributes<SwaggerTagAttribute>()
            .Select(t => t.Tags)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (tags != null && TagsToHide.Intersect(tags).Any())
        {
            operation.tags = new List<string> {"Remove Me "};
        }
    }

    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, IApiExplorer apiExplorer)
    {
        foreach (var value in swaggerDoc.paths.Values)
        {
            if (value.post != null && value.post.tags.Contains("Remove Me"))
                value.post = null;

            if (value.get != null && value.get.tags.Contains("Remove Me"))
                value.get = null;

            if (value.put != null && value.put.tags.Contains("Remove Me"))
                value.put = null;

            if (value.delete != null && value.delete.tags.Contains("Remove Me"))
                value.delete = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And registered as such:

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.OperationFilter<RemoveTaggedOperationsFilter>();
                    c.DocumentFilter<RemoveTaggedOperationsFilter>();
                });
```

I feel that this is inefficient and hacky to tag something for removal later when I have access to it earlier. Is there any way that I just remove the route from the within `IOperationFilter.Apply` rather than wait for the `IDocumentFilter` and scan through it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone had posted an answer earlier and said they'd post code once they got a chance. They have deleted their answer for some reason but it got me to a better solution.

Rather than using `IOperationFilter` to tag the route and then `IDocumentFilter` to remove the route later you can just use `IDocumentFilter` to find the custom attribute and remove it in one fell swoop. The code is below:

```
public class HideTaggedOperationsFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    private List<string> TagsToHide;

    public HideTaggedOperationsFilter()
    {
        TagsToHide = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TagsToHide"].Split(',').ToList();
    }

    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, IApiExplorer apiExplorer)
    {
        if (_tagsToHide == null) return;

        foreach (var apiDescription in apiExplorer.ApiDescriptions)
        {
            var tags = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor
                .GetCustomAttributes<SwaggerTagAttribute>()
                .Select(t => t.Tags)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (tags == null || !_tagsToHide.Intersect(tags).Any())
                continue;

            var route = "/" + apiDescription.Route.RouteTemplate.TrimEnd('/');
            swaggerDoc.paths.Remove(route);
        }
    }
}

public class SwaggerTagAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string[] Tags { get; }

    public SwaggerTagAttribute(params string[] tags)
    {
        this.Tags = tags;
    }
}
```

Register the `IDocumentFilter`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableSwagger(c =>
{
    ...
    c.DocumentFilter<HideTaggedOperationsFilter>();
});
```

Then just decorate a route like so:

```
 [SwaggerTag("MobileOnly")]
 public IHttpActionResult SendTest(Guid userId)
 {
    return OK();
 }
```

`Edit:` There are some issue posts on the GitHub page for SwashBuckle that recommend setting each of the HTTP verbs to null on the `swaggerDoc.path` in `Apply`. I found this to break a lot of auto code generators like AutoRest so I am simply removing the path as a whole. (It looks more succinct too)

Comment: This approach will not work if you have the same route with different verbs, but only want to disable some. Ie having GET /transcations and POST /transactions, both are removed when only 1 action method is decorated with the custom attribute. You would need to also take the http method into consideration.

Comment: @ParaJaco that's a great point. It probably wouldn't be too difficult to extend it to take the HTTP verbs into account.

Comment: Could I decorate the whole controller ?

Comment: Good question. I'm not 100% sure as I have not tried it. Feel free to give it a try and let me know. If it doesn't work maybe I can see what would need to be done to extend it to be able to support controller attribute decoration.